# How to make slf4j-log4j12 only provided when on dev IDE ,maven

Tags: maven, slf4j

I hope to provide a api to my client which only needs slfj-api. But when dev using ide, logs will be logged using slf4j-log4j12 .

Is there a way to do this with maven.

I try declaring it as provided scope, but it does not work.

Comment: You could maybe use a maven profile and then have the slf4j-log4j12 dependency only in the profile and activate that profile in you ide.

Comment: you want to use slf4j-log4j12 in your tests or in a running application / j2ee application deployed in a local server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have marked the slf4j-log4j12 dependency as provided like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then another dependency in your project may have slf4j-log4j12 as a transitive dependency. Try running the `mvn dependency:tree` command. This will show you all the transitive dependencies of each of your dependencies. If slf4j-log4j12 is being pulled in you can exclude it like this.

```
<!-- Dependency with slf4j-log4j12 as a transitive dependency -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>my.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```